# Issues sending Fetch delete request in React to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux, fetch

I'm able to send get and put methods fine, but am surprisingly not able to send a delete fetch request from my Redux action to my Rails backend. This is even more perplexing because in Postman I'm able to hit the Destroy route fine. I've searched all over for a fix, but haven't found anything that works. I have an onClick function that triggers the Redux action that sends this request:

```
 export const deleteQuestion = (questionId, routerHistory) => {
   return dispatch => {
     return fetch(`${API_URL}/questions/${questionId}`, {
       method: 'DELETE',      
     }).then(response => {
         dispatch(removeQuestion(questionId));
         routerHistory.replace(`/`);
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error));
   };
 };
```

I've checked numerous times to make sure the syntax and route is fine. questionId is also the correct question ID. However, no matter what I do, the Destroy method in the Questions controller won't recognize the request. I've checked the route in Rails and it exists. I don't get any errors, no request is ever sent to the server, and nothing is returned, not in terminal, the console, or anything.

This is the Github account: https://github.com/jwolfe890/react_project1

I'd really appreciate any insight anyone has. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the output in the rails server when make the request?

Comment: it doesn't even contain output and i have no idea why. the get and post requests are still working fine in the app though.

Comment: Does you Rails backend accept DELETE requests?

Comment: i'm assuming it does. it has a Destroy method in the controller and the delete route is defined in the routes and shows up when i do rails routes

Comment: Something in the browser console that you can add to the question? The network tab?

Comment: nothing unusual shows up in the console. https://github.com/jwolfe890/react_project1

Comment: @Dog "I'm assuming it does". Maybe it doesn't (saying that you confirmed that GET and POST work). Try via `curl` or use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/postman) and check whether the results are the same.

Comment: in Postman it hits the destroy route fine. it's something to do with the Fetch call. nothing appears in Network.

Comment: I'd like to second @SebastiánPalma in that you should check the network tab of the browser's development tools to see if the delete request is actually triggered (registered as a request) and if so, also the result of the request (error message, status code, ...). Depending on that, one would have to look at the back end or the front end.

Comment: the Network tab doesn't register the delete request at all. Only the get, post, and puts requests work. It works fine in Postman and Curl though for Delete which makes me think it's not a Rails issue, but a Fetch one.

Comment: In that case @Dog, add a breakpoint to the fetch method call to see if it is ever reached at all.

Comment: i tried that. it hits inside the Fetch action above the first dispatch, but then that's the last point I can pause it at. So it's definitely making it inside the method at least.

Comment: Update line 18 in your questions controller to `@question = Question.find(params[:id])` and see the problem is in your dispatcher.

Comment: naw that didn't work :/ i'm pretty sure it's not a rails issue because the delete requests are working with postman and curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `deleteQuestion` method returns an anonymous function with a `dispatch` parameter which never seems to be called ([Calling code](https://github.com/jwolfe890/react_project1/blob/2c32379321e7cceba9dcaa4abbf6e59838fbcbaa/stumped-app-client/src/containers/questionCard.js#L20)). Only `deleteQuestion` is called but not the function returned by it.

Because it is called by a click handler I'd say you actually want something like this:

```
export const deleteQuestion = (questionId, routerHistory) => {   
  fetch(`${API_URL}/questions/${questionId}`, {
     method: 'DELETE',      
  }).then(response => {
     dispatch(removeQuestion(questionId));
     routerHistory.replace(`/`);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

Or if you want to return the promise, you could of course change it to:

```
export const deleteQuestion = (questionId, routerHistory) => {   
  return fetch(`${API_URL}/questions/${questionId}`, {
     method: 'DELETE',      
  }).then(response => {
     dispatch(removeQuestion(questionId));
     routerHistory.replace(`/`);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

If you want to dynamically inject the dispatch function, you could leave your original code, but would have to call the method like this:

```
deleteQuestion(this.state.question.id, history)(myDispatchMethod);
```